# Magento with angular js

Tags: magento2, rest-api, php-7, mongo, angularjs

Currently i have developed Magento 2.2 with Angular js 4. i create rest api in magento and angular will get response from magento api. for in future my client want to use Magento 2.2 as a backend with serve MySQL database in between they want to use mongodb and front-end will angular js.

so the architecture will magento will create api and post to mongodb and mongodb will sent the data to angular.

is it possible to do that?
 for more details please find image for architecture

[image]